# Talend - Rename File in Windows with a string retrieved by a tjava component

Tags: talend

Using Talend, I want to rename a file in a Windows machine with a filename that I don't know in advance retrieved from a field in a fixed length file. I intended to use the tFileCopy to do it, but I didn't know how to pass the field value from the tfileInputPositional to the tfileCopy component - Destination filename. So, I tried to rename the file exclusively with a java code routine executed with the tjava component. Nevertheless, after I successfully retrieved the name with the code routine I didn't manage to rename the file also with that code routine  cause the file.renameTo method doesn't seem to work (known java issue).

So how from  the tFileCopy component can I reference a value that I obtain running a tjava component? Is there any other way to pass a variable value to the tFileCopy component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass value from tfileInputPositional  to tJavaRow (or your tJava) component and store the file name in a global var using

```
globalMap.put("filename","yourderivedfilename");
```

now in your tFileCopy component you can check RENAME option and give file name as

```
globalMap.get("filename")
```

and also you can check remove source file checkbox or use tFileDelete to remove old version of file

Comment: don't forget to add the String casting to it! (String)globalMap.get

Comment: First thank you for your help. I'm newbie to Talend/Java so please be patient with my need for further clarifications. If I include the reference to the globalMap variable in the middle of my code routine I get «globalMap cannot be resolved». How I overcome this?

Comment: this code routine you are adding inside tJava or tJavaRow component? As if you do here, (String) globalMap.get() should be available. Can you post your code sample and job snapshot.